# QTP/UFT - Adding comments to code in Editor view

Tags: comments, qtp, hp-uft

How do I add comments in my code via the Editor view for my Actions? I know this is a simple question, but I haven't been able to figure it out, and this seems almost impossible to Google for.

I've tried some of the standard commenting types, none of which have worked:

- `//`
- `/* */`
- `#`
- `--`

I know I can add text to the Description attribute for an Action, but I'd like to be able to comment out specific lines in my code as needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean the expert view where you see the generated code?
You can use the single quote character for that:

```
' The user needs to be informed that the test is ready to run, so 
' he can take appropriate actions before continue or Cancel if needed.
If MsgBox("The test is ready to start.", VbOKCancel) <> VbOK then
    ExitTest
End If
```

Shortcut to comment/uncomment blocks: Ctrl+M and Ctrl+Shift+M